# How to update values manually in tensorflow during run time

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am new to **tensorflow**.

In the following code I am trying to achieve the following
1.modify the output of the `graph (ie y)`, during run time i.e. when running the training algorithm. 
2. I want to update value stored in the tensor `y` and use this new value while training.

I was wondering if there is any way to achieve this.

Any help in this regard would be really appreciated.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import sys

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str,                default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                  help='Directory for storing input data')
FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step =   tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                  y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: Can you please mention what piece is of code is not working or what error are you getting?

Comment: The above code works, but I need to modify the values stored in y during run time (ie when i pass the training image inputs) and use that modified value of y to compute the cross_entropy and train the network. I was wondering if there is a way to do that. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand your question... I think you misunderstood how the training procedure works. When you run optimization algorithm you do not update y. Instead you update W and b (the parameters or weights of the network). This in turn changes y. When optimization finishes you W and b have values that make y and y_ very similar.

Comment: @Asterisk, Thank you for the message. Heres what I am trying to achieve, I want to update few of the values stored in y(which i think can be done only during run time) and then train this modified network.

Comment: @Asterisk, by run time i mean whenever I pass inputs to the network by using a .run command